# go:embed filename extension patterns

Tags: go, embed

Using [go:embed](https://pkg.go.dev/embed) it's possible to embed files:

```golang
package main

import "embed"

//go:embed dir
var MyFs embed.FS
```

"embed" uses the [path.Match](https://pkg.go.dev/path#Match) call internally.

This doesn't work:

```
//go:embed dir/*{.js,tsx}
```

I don't see a way to match by filename extensions, is there any way to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specify the patterns separately:

```
//go:embed dir/*.js dir/*.tsx
var MyFs embed.FS
```

Another option is to include the directory and ensure that the names of the files that you don't want to include start with a  `_` or `.`.

```
//go:embed dir
```

Comment: This is the best solution I've found, although it's cumbersome if matching many types of extensions, and it'd be great if the Go developers extended path.Match a bit to allow a few regex features like lists of matches: `{js,tsx}`.

Comment: @ChristianStewart The suggested change to path.Match breaks the [Go compatibility guarantee](https://go.dev/doc/go1compat).  One option is to extend the syntax supported by go:embed and gate that syntax on the module's Go version.

Comment: that's not what the compatibility guarantee is for, APIs have been changed / extended in the past. As long as the previous code doesn't break. For example, adding different types of match specifiers wouldn't break older code: see: The APIs may grow, acquiring new packages and features, but not in a way that breaks existing Go 1 code.

Comment: This is a case where previous code breaks. The proposal changes `{` and `}` from plain characters to special characters.  That change breaks existing code that assumes that `{` and `}` are plain characters.